# jQuery animate w/marginTop not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a test running here: http://raglefant.com/test.php where I have this jQuery in the header:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideable_header').stop().delay(2000).animate(
            {marginTop: '-=290'}
        ,1000,function() {
    });

    $('#hideable_header').click(function() {
        var position = parseInt($("#hideable_header").css("margin-top"),10);
        console.log('Position: ' + position);
        if (position == 0)
        {
            $('#hideable_header').stop().animate(
                    {marginTop: '-=290'}
                ,1000,function() {
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#hideable_header').stop().animate(
                    {marginTop: '+=290'}
                ,1000,function() {
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the div:

```
<div id="hideable_header" style="position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 300px; background: #000; z-index:9999;"></div>
```

This is working fine in Chrome, but not in IE9. If I click the DIV it should change the margintop to hide or show the DIV, but nothing happens in IE9.
If I open the devtools in IE9 though, everything works fine without any errors appearing. But as soon as I close the page and open it again, it still fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in IE9, but not how you would expect it to in IE8.  In IE8, the initial position is NaN, so I would recommend setting margin-top to 0 in the inline style.